# sbt-release from jenkins no user input

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sbt-release

How can you do an sbt release from jenkins using a jenkinsfile with non-interactive sbt-release syntax?

For some reason this does not work.  Locally works

```
sbt "release with-defaults"
```

In Jenkins does not work

```
sh "sbt \\'release with-defaults\\'"
```

Output in jenkins shows

```
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mNo valid parser available.[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m"release  "[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m ^[0m
```

I believe the quotes around `"release with-defaults"` are required. It seems like sbt is executing first, going into the sbt console, then trying to execute `release...` next which then it shows the sbt error "no valid parser available"

Comment: I tried adding an alias `addCommandAlias("releaseSilent", "release with-defaults")` while it works locally, it still seems like in jenkins it hangs waiting for user input.

Answer (score 1):

Try flipping your quotes: `sh 'sbt "release with-defaults"'`, this is working for me without requiring any user input. You can also specify other options with spaces between the key and value: `sh 'sbt "release with-defaults default-tag-exists-answer o"'` in this case it will override a tag existing already.